# How to add glow effect on custom marker

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

My app has custom images and they are set as marker icons based on different conditions. I'm using marker's `setIcon()` method to do that.

My question is, how can I add a glow effect on a marker when it is selected. I have the selected/unselected logic in place, all I want to do is create a glow effect around the shape of the image used as icon of a marker. 
Sample (the glow in question needn't be in rounded shape):

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: setShadowLayer() may work better for this effect

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use blurmaskfilter with outer setting? Maybe playing with paint and color can help

```
Bitmap alpha = origin.extractAlpha();
BlurMaskFilter blurMaskFilter = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setMaskFilter(blurMaskFilter);
paint.setColor(0xffffffff);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(origin);
canvas.drawBitmap(alpha, 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: And how do I add it as a bitmap to the marker using `setIcon()`?

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory#fromBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and set icon

Comment: Let me do that. I assume `origin` here is the image drawable of marker, yes?

Comment: Yes exactly! Let me know the result!

Comment: How do I use `origin`? I'm still stuck there.

Comment: It depends on how did you create the marker icon. Is it a bitmap? A drawable?

Comment: I'm using it as a drawable `marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.markerIcon));`

Comment: You can get a bitmap from the drawable used for markerBitmap icon : BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.markerIcon); and then go on with the abovementioned

Comment: So I did something similar and got it to work but the entire marker is black now with glowing edges. Can we just make the edges glow and not the markers?

Comment: And how do I draw another image on top of it?

Comment: You can by using canvas Canvas canvas = new Canvas(); canvas.setBitmap(alpha); canvas.drawBitmap(markericon, new Matrix(), null); it should work, I'm on mobile,can't test it now

Comment: Let me try that as soon as I get home from work. Thanks a ton!